# Angular service function is undefined - MVC6

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc, angular-services

I am trying to write a login service (in typescript), which posts the username and password to my C# controller. The C# controller then makes a service call that hits my database to authenticate the user, but that is out of scope for this question.

The issue is that when I try to call my authentication function (which is found in my angular service) from my angular controller, I get an error in my console that it is `unable to get property 'Authenticate' of undefined or null reference.`

Here is the base class (Handler) for my services:

```
module app.Services {
export class HttpHandlerService {
    httpService: ng.IHttpService;
    handlerUrl: string;

    constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
        super();
        this.httpService = $http;
    }

    useGetHandler(params: any): ng.IPromise<any> {
        var result: ng.IPromise<any> = this.httpService.get(this.handlerUrl, params)
            .then((response: any): ng.IPromise<any> => this.handlerResponded(response, params));
        return result;
    }

    usePostHandler(params: any): ng.IPromise<any> {
        var result: ng.IPromise<any> = this.httpService.post(this.handlerUrl, params)
            .then((response: any): ng.IPromise<any> => this.handlerResponded(response, params));
        return result;
    }

    handlerResponded(response: any, params: any): any {
        response.data.requestParams = params;
        return response.data;
    }

}
}
```

Then my login service inherits it:

```
module app.Services {
export interface ILoginService {
    Authenticate(email: string, password: string): ng.IPromise<any>;
}

export class LoginService extends Services.HttpHandlerService {

    static $inject = ['$http'];

    constructor($http: ng.IHttpService) {
        this.handlerUrl = '/Login';
        super($http);
    }

    // Authentication function I am attempting to call
    Authenticate(email: string, password: string): ng.IPromise<any> {

        // I have not completed the actual request that is being sent 
        var config: any = {};
        var request = {
            "Email": email,
            "Password": password
        }

        return this.usePostHandler(config);
    }
}
angular.module('App').factory('loginService', LoginService);
}
```

Here is my login controller where I'm calling the service:

```
module app.Login {

import Services = app.Services;

interface ILoginController {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    login(): void;
}

class LoginController implements ILoginController{
    email: string;
    password: string;
    loginService: Services.ILoginService;

    loginForm: any;
    static $inject = ["$state"];
    constructor(private $state: ng.ui.IStateParamsService, loginService: Services.ILoginService) {
        this.email = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

    login() {
        if (this.loginForm.$invalid) {
            return;
        }

        var request = this.loginService.Authenticate(this.email, this.password);

        request.success(function (data) {
            console.log("User authenticated.");
        });

        request.error(function () {
            console.log("Error: User not authenticated.");
        });
    }
}
angular.module('App').controller('loginController', LoginController);
}
```

And finally my c# controller"

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("/Login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    // . . . .
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

**EDIT:**

This is the javascript generated from the login service typescript:

```
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || function (d, b) {

for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];

function __() { this.constructor = d; }

d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());

};

var app;

(function (app) {

var Services;

(function (Services) {

    var LoginService = (function (_super) {

        __extends(LoginService, _super);

        function LoginService($http) {

            this.handlerUrl = '/Login';

            _super.call(this, $http);

        }

        LoginService.prototype.Authenticate = function (email, password) {

            var config = {};

            var request = {

                "Email": email,

                "Password": password

            };

            return this.usePostHandler(config);

        };

        LoginService.$inject = ['$http'];

        return LoginService;

    })(Services.HttpHandlerService);

    Services.LoginService = LoginService;

    angular.module('App').factory('loginService', LoginService);

})(Services = app.Services || (app.Services = {}));

})(app || (app = {}));
```

I do get an error, only in IE, that `_super` is undefined.

Comment: What is the exact error message? That Authenticate function is undefined or loginService property is undefined?

Comment: `Unable to get property 'Authenticate' of undefined or null reference.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unable to get property 'Authenticate' of undefined or null reference.` means that `this.loginService` was not properly injected by Angular.

You can try changing this:

`static $inject = ["$state"];`

to this:

`static $inject = ["$state", "LoginService"];`

[Proper Dependency Injection in Your AngularJS TypeScript Apps](http://sirarsalih.com/2014/08/04/proper-dependency-injection-in-your-angularjs-typescript-apps/)

Comment: Actually, it appears that it did not update the JS. Now, I am receiving an `unknown provider: LoginServiceProvider` error, which is probably just a missing reference